# Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts exception while connecting from .NET

Tags: .net, mysql

I have connected my .net application with my sql server using mysql connector package,

I used local LAN environment sql server, which has the series of 190.168.191.XXX

When I try to connect internet zone server which has 192.168.3.XXX. i can't able to connect the server, 
**It shows unable to find the host**

What do I have to do for connecting to an internet zone server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved,
after disable the Firewall in server mechine it's works fine.